# Error OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large') Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, overflow, decimal

Estoy intentando hacer una operación aritmética bastante simple en Python 3.6, pero no soy capaz a conseguir el resultado porque me dice que es demasiado grande.

```
import numpy as np
H=20
a2= 0.925310252    
k= np.pi /40000 
b1= 0.0000130992
H**((a2-k)/b1)
```

La parte del exponente sale bien, pero cuando intento elevar la H a dicho exponente me sale el error "OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')".
He estado buscando soluciones y casi todas me remiten a la librería Decimal, pero no consigo dar con la sintaxis correcta para hacerlo. También he probado a redondear el resultado del exponente con np.round(a,3) pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error y lo mismo al redondear las variables de entrada . ¿Alguien me puede echar una mano? Soy bastante inexperta y seguramente tenga fácil arreglo.

Gracias de antemano

Comment: En python los enteros no tienen límite de tamaño (salvo por lo que permita la memoria RAM del ordenador). Pero en este caso no estás trabajando con enteros debido a que tu exponente es racional. En ese caso Python se ve forzado a usar funciones que manejan `float` y esas sí tienen un límite (del orden de `10**308`). De todas formas, como @CandidMoe indica en su respuesta, el exponente con que trabajas, además de ser racional **es enorme**, así que quizás has tenido suerte a fin de cuentas de que no sea entero, pues si no se habría puesto a calcularlo y el resultado sería larguísimo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una de las herramientas más valiosas en la depuración de programas en la instrucción `print()`. Con ella puedes ver lo que está pasando:

```
import numpy as np
H=20
a2= 0.925310252
k= np.pi /40000
b1= 0.0000130992
print(f"a2={a2}")
print(f"k={k}")
print(f"exponente={(a2-k)/b1}")
```

produce:

```
a2=0.925310252
k=7.853981633974483e-05
exponente=70632.68842247315
```

o sea, estas tratando de calcular 20 ** 70632. Ese es número bastante grande, considerando que en **todo** el Universo solo hay 10 ** 80 partículas.

Sospecho que algo anda mal en tu formula.